# Adobe installers not working in Mojave

Tags: macos, mojave, adobe

Since I installed Mojave, all my Adobe apps with this installer or uninstaller icon:
[image: Adobe installer icon]

don't work at all. I've tried this on a fresh install of Mojave on my MacBook Air 2014 and it still doesn't work. Trying it on a MacBook pro Mojave, it works perfectly. I don't really know what the problem is.

[image: Adobe installer is not responding]

Comment: Have you tried with the latest CC Installer, which I think is 4.6.0.384 ? oops, nope, just checked, it's now 4.7.0.400 https://helpx.adobe.com/creative-cloud/release-note/cc-release-notes.html?mv=product&mv2=accc#

Comment: Which Adobe app is it ?

Comment: @Tetsujin I'll try to get the latest CC installers, but this same installer has worked on other MacBooks running Mojave without problems.

Comment: @Buscar웃 It's Adobe CC 2018, all apps.

Comment: delete it and get new one